# django - AttributeError: type object 'file' has no attribute 'set_user'

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, django-models

I have created a model named `file`. It was running well, then I created an element inside the class named `set_user` which gave an error. So, I removed it. But, I think it's not deleted my my database as I am getting this error while trying to migrate:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 10, in
>   
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 363, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 355, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line
>   283, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line
>   330, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py",
>   line 96, in handle
>       loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line
>   52, in **init**
>       self.build_graph()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line
>   203, in build_graph
>       self.load_disk()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line
>   114, in load_disk
>       migration_module = import_module("%s.%s" % (module_name, migration_name))   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/**init**.py",
>   line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 994, in _gcd_import   File
>   "", line 971, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
>   File "", line 665, in _load_unlocked
>   File "", line 678, in
>   exec_module   File "", line 219, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed   File "/home/hashir/website/one/migrations/0017_auto_20171222_2108.py", line
>   11, in 
>       class Migration(migrations.Migration):   File "/home/hashir/website/one/migrations/0017_auto_20171222_2108.py", line
>   21, in Migration
>       field=models.ForeignKey(default=one.models.file.set_user, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE,
>   to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL), AttributeError: type object 'file' has
>   no attribute 'set_user'

Here's models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class file(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    FILE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('audio','Audio'),
        ('games','Games'),
        ('videos','Videos'),
        ('applications','Applications'),
        ('books','Books/Docs'),
        ('others','Others')
        )
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=12,choices=FILE_TYPE_CHOICES,default='others')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=6000)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('one:user')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: You haven't included enough information. Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Mind the case of your class https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names File instead of file.

Comment: @Alasdair I've included

Answer (score 0):

Just delete migrations folder from the project and apply the migrations again.
Then run these 3 commands:

```
python manage.py migrate yourapp zero
python manage.py makemigrations yourapp
python manage.py migrate yourapp
```

Comment: This might have worked in your case, but it won't work in all cases. Think carefully before you delete migrations that you have already applied. You risk your database and migrations getting out of sync, which can be very hard to fix.